# C# Login form with User Authentication with SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, ado.net

I am new to SQL Server and C#. I am working on a login form that checks if the user is an admin or a basic user. In my SQL Server, I created a table that stores username, password, and role (admin or basic user). The saved data are the following:

- For admin: username = admin, password = admin, role = admin
- For basic user: username = user, password = user, role = user

If the user enters username and password "admin" it should be directed to the admin page else it would be user page.

This is my code:

```
string query = "SELECT * from tbl_login WHERE Username = @username and password=@password";

con.Open();

SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", tbusername.Text);
sqlcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", tbpswlog.Text);
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();

SqlDataAdapter sqlsda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
sqlsda.Fill(dtbl);

con.Close();

if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    this.Hide();

    if (tbusername.Equals("admin"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as an Admin");
        AdminHome fr1 = new AdminHome();
        fr1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as a User");
        UserHome fr2 = new UserHome();
        fr2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password");
}
```

I know this code lacks and wrong.

EDIT:

I tried this code below

```
if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 1)
{
    this.Hide();

    if (dtbl.Rows[0]["role"].ToString().Equals("admin"))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as an Admin");
        AdminHome fr1 = new AdminHome();
        fr1.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as a User");
        UserHome fr2 = new UserHome();
        fr2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password");
}
```

But even if I entered username admin and password admin, it would say "You entered as a user".

Comment: What is the platform target for this? Are you planning on making a WPF application, .NET Core web app, etc.?

Comment: windows form application c#

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are using Windows Forms over a WPF application?

Comment: Side note: *don't store plain text passwords*, this can get you in trouble, use `Add`, not `AddWithValue` as the value has to be inferred, use `using` statements to ensure objects are disposed of. Where is `tbusername` coming from; you need to be getting values from `dtbl`... So for checking role example: `If dtbl.Rows[0].Item["role"].ToString().Equals("admin")`

Comment: Please clarify your question. Not sure if you're asking about best practices, if your code is not working, or something else.

Comment: We were told to create a windows form application, its for a school project

Comment: So far, I see nothing too wrong. But there are a couple things you could consider: a) Do not store plaintext passwords in the database, you should store the password hashes instead. b) If you move into `WPF` and `.net core` in the future you could execute it on linux/mac...

Comment: this code actually works but its working the wrong way. When I entered username admin and password admin it would print "You logged in as a user" .

Comment: [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: When you step through your code in the debugger, what comes back from the database? What is the row count and what is the value in the Role field?

Comment: when I tried this If dtbl.Rows[0].Item["role"].ToString().Equals("admin")
there is an error with the Item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to retrieve the value of the role. Don't retrieve unnecessary data. Check the name of the column in the database and correct if necessary.

Keep you database objects local so you can be sure they are closed and disposed. The `using` blocks that care of this even if there is an error.

You don't need a DataTable or a DataAdapter. Using `.ExecuteScalar` will return the first column of the first row of the result set which is exactly what you want to know. The role.

```
    private void ValidateUser()
    {
        string query = "SELECT role from tbl_login WHERE Username = @username and password=@password";
        string returnValue = "";
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("YourConnectionString"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
            {
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbusername.Text;
                sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = tbpswlog.Text;
                con.Open();
                returnValue = (string)sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
//EDIT to avoid NRE 
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnValue))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password");
            return;
        }
        returnValue = returnValue.Trim();
        if (returnValue == "Admin")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as an Admin");
            AdminHome fr1 = new AdminHome();
            fr1.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
        else if (returnValue == "User")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You are logged in as a User");
            UserHome fr2 = new UserHome();
            fr2.Show();
            this.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Comment: When I clicked log in it won't log in nothing happens.

Comment: Did you call this sub from the click event?

Comment: Did you add your real connection string where it says "YourConnectionString"? Put a break point in the method and step through the code.

Comment: Yes I added the my connection string

Comment: Now add a break point and check the value of `returnValue` after the `sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar` runs.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about break point my professor didn't told us about that. But how do I get rid of the whitespaces? the returnValue has whitespaces that is why even if I enter admin it won't work

Comment: Before the if block add a line `returnValue = returnValue.Trim()` Trim will remove white space before and after the string.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works now thank you very much

Comment: For the incorrect username or password, it will have this error 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The first if `if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnValue))` checks for null. Perhaps a `return;` directly below `MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password");` I am sorry for all the trouble.

Comment: I added 'return;' below the 'MessageBox.Show("Incorrect username or password);' but it will still have error in the line 'returnValue = returnValue.Trim();' saying Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: See EDIT to my answer. First, check for null. If returnValue is null we alert the user and leave the method. Then we know it is not null and we can `.Trim() ` and check the role value.

Answer (score -1):

Reading the comment, you need the following in the if statement instead of what you wrote.

```
if (tbusername.Text == "admin")
```

Comment: In addition to this, my preference would also be to convert user input for the username to lowercase. This allows for more reliable comparisons. For simple string comparisons, == is generally what should be used as opposed to .Equals().

Comment: I tried this and worked but this is not checking the data in the database when I entered username Admin with password admin it would logged in as a user. I tried if (tbusername.Equals("admin") but I know it wouldn't check the database, it would only check the textbox.

Comment: I would suggest ``if (tbusername.Text.ToUpper() == "ADMIN") `` as ToUpper()) is generally preferred in .Net, but I'm not certain in backing it up so I didn't write it this way

Comment: In the comments it is suggested that you query the user's type and only check the query's answer for the type