# How to filter results of a combobox based on LoginuserID from SQL table

Tags: c#, sql

I have a project I'm working on where I have an SQL database with login and location tables. I have a field in my login table called 'LoginUserID'. Based on whatever ID number is placed here, '100, 200', etc. I need this to filter the results the user can see of the location combobox. The combobox is getting its results from the location table in my SQL database. I am new to c#, so any help is much appreciated. In my mind, I want it to check the value of the login table called 'LoginUserID', and if the login ID is '100' for example, it will only show a certain location(s) based on that in the combobox for the user to select. But I have no idea how to do that. I have been attempting to google/youtube this issue and I have not found anything.

I tried to create an SQL connection with the Login table, where I told it to select 'LoginUserID' from the login table. I then attempted to compare that data using an if statement.
Example:

```
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("Select LoginUserID from LoginTable", conn2);
            SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter();
           da2.SelectCommand = cmd2;

         
            int LoginUserID =  Convert.ToInt32(LoginUserID);
           if (LoginUserID = "100") ;
```

But at this point, I do not know what command to put here to filter the combobox results based on certain userID's. I am also getting a 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int' error for the if statement.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Login form with User Authentication with SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58187736/c-sharp-login-form-with-user-authentication-with-sql-server-database)

Comment: As an aside, you would probably find Entity Framework Core **MUCH** easier to work with than data adapters. EF and Linq are a very powerful combination that make development much easier. Worth spending the time to learn them, rather than break your head on data adapters.